# How I declare accordion in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ajax Part: Here I want declare class of accordion inside ajax for looping data from database. How I can display accordion as looping from DB?

```
    var htmlAppend = jQuery("<div id='accordion'></div>").html(htmlTempItem).find('a[id ="collapse"]')
    //.attr('class', 'collapsed')
    .attr('role', 'button')
    .attr('data-toggle', 'collapse')
    .attr('data-parent', '#accordion')
    .attr('href', '#collapseTwo' + i + '')
    .attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
    .attr('aria-controls', 'collapseTwo' + i + '')
    .html('Property Item '+i+'').parents("div[data-id=accordion]").html();

    htmlAppend = jQuery("<div id='accordion'></div>").html(htmlTempItem).find('div[data-type="txtTitleNumber"]')
    .attr('data-TitleNumber', item.TitleNumber).html(item.TitleNumber).parents("div[data-id=accordion]").html();
```

This is for HTML part:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Property Item #
     </a>
   </h4>
   </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Create HTML string inside loop with specific selectors and then use `$(selector).accordion()`

Comment: Is it I declare correct?  `find('a[id ="collapse"]')`